# react-progressbar.js content does not render in react project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I would like to have a circular progress bar in my react.js project. Following [kimmobrunfeldt's react-progressbar.js installation notes](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/react-progressbar.js), I managed to include said library in my project. However, for some reason unknown to me, the actual progress bar does not render. The DOM inspector indicates that the progress bar's wrapper is there, but not its content. No errors show up when building with npm.

Here is my react.js project setup:

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');


var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/app');
  module.exports = {
  entry: [ APP_DIR + '/index.jsx'],
  output: { path: BUILD_DIR, filename: 'bundle.js'},
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.jsx?/, include : APP_DIR, loader: 'babel'},
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
    ]
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "hello-react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015",
      "react"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack -d --watch"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.8",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "react-progressbar.js": "^0.2.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.4.5",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.8",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "react": "^0.14.8",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2",
    "webpack-loader-modules": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

**index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import progressBar from 'react-progressbar.js';

// ...

// ...
var Circle = progressBar.Circle;

class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (

      <div>
      <p> Hello React!</p>

      <Circle
          progress={1}
          text={'test'}
          initialAnimate= {true}
          containerClassName= {'progressbar-container'}
          />
      </div>

    );
  }
}

// ...


render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: I then get a Module not found error. I don't think it's a matter of wrong pathnames as the project per se compiles just fine.

Comment: Are you can provide a full error message?

Comment: Sure. If I leave out the suffix this is what I get:

ERROR in ./src/client/app/index.jsx
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react-progressbar' in /Users/UserX/Desktop/react-hello-world/src/client/app
 @ ./src/client/app/index.jsx 11:24-52

Comment: Did you forget to specify style option? containerStyle={{ width: '200px',height:'200px'}}

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, containerClassName should start with .

```
<Circle
            progress={this.state.progress}
            text={'test'}
            options={options}
            initialAnimate={true}
            containerStyle={containerStyle}
            containerClassName={'.progressbar'}
/>
```

Source: https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/react-progressbar.js/tree/master

Besides that, I have no clue...

Comment: That is true, however, I deliberately left some of the arguments out because otherwise the entire DOM does not render... Remarkably, even then there are no error messages from npm...